# merge two columns then group by

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle11g

I have the follwoing table and data, i want to merge loc1 and loc2 in one column and remove duplicate values from loc column then group it according to group_no column.

```
drop table test;
create table test (loc1 number(9), loc2 number(9), group_no number(9));
insert into test values(2,3,1);
insert into test values(2,9,1);
insert into test values(4,3,1);
insert into test values(6,8,2);
insert into test values(11,7,2);
insert into test values(20,15,2);
insert into test values(15,14,2);
insert into test values(21,31,3);
insert into test values(31,32,3);
```

the expected results are :

```
loc   group_no
2        1
3        1
9        1
4        1
6        2
8        2 
11       2
20      2 
15       2
21       3
31       3
32       3
```

regards

Comment: can you show the expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your expected result, you want to group by `loc` rather than `group_no`.

```
select t.loc, max(t.group_no)
(
    select loc1 as loc, group_no from test

    union

    select loc2 as loc, group_no from test
) t
group by t.loc
order by 2,1
```

Comment: But group by is not order ascending